# How to setup virtualenvwrapper in zsh under linux mint?

Tags: linux, virtualenv, zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh

I use virtualenvwrapper from apt.
It's working OK with bash but I recently switched to zsh.
Now when I try `workon` in zsh I get `zsh: command not found: workon`
Because I'm using oh-my-zsh script/plugins I thought it will be sufficient to add virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper plugins to my `.zshrc` plugins=.
But it did not help. What else I need to configure to make it work under zsh?

PS to be clear -  I still can use bash for this - nothing broken here...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I just test it on ubuntu 14.04 and i had the same problem. 
To fix it add this to your .zshrc

```
 source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

or run this in terminal

```
 echo source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: In Mac OS X I had to do: ``echo source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh >> ~/.zshrc``

Comment: For me on ubuntu 14.04 (and generally following virtualenvwrapper's installation instructions), I needed to add `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` to .zshrc. Also, if you're using a nonstandard location for your virtualenvs, be sure to add `export WORKON_HOME=/path/to/virtualenvs` before the source line.

Comment: If you installed `py27-virtualenvwrapper` with Macports on OSX:
`echo source /opt/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper2.7.sh >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: Whats about virtualenv in ArchLinux?

Comment: According to arch wiki the path is /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
I havent tested it (i dont have an arch installation) but probably
`echo source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh >> ~/.zshrc` will do the trick ;)

Comment: I am using lazy wrapper `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh` it works fine with shortcuts `workon` or `makevirtualenv` as such.